# API en Laravel/Passport me devuelve un token diferente en cada petición

Tags: laravel, api, tokens, passport

Soy novato en esto de las API's y al hacer una con Laravel/Passport me ha surgido una duda.

El caso es que estoy obteniendo el acces_token de un usuario mediante la ruta ejemplo.com/oauth/token y aunque está funcionando correctamente no entiendo porque cada vez que lanzo la petición me devuelve un token nuevo.

**¿No debería ser siempre el mismo hasta que este expire?**

El problema es que no imagino el funcionamiento así ya que mi proyecto consta de la API, una Web APP y una APP Android. **Entonces si se solicita el token desde Android mientras está iniciada la sesión en la web APP el token cambiará y tendré problemas.**

Como veis no acabo de entender el flujo de regeneración de tokens.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ese Token que devuelve la ruta ejemplo.com/oauth/token, es el que tiene que utilizar tu cliente para conectarse a las rutas que tengas protegidas con el token en tu Aplicación Web.

Laravel/passport te permite crear varios tipos de token para proteger rutas, un token general, token por scope y token de acceso personal.

Una estrategia puede ser crear un solo token para todos tus rutas y que lo guarde la configuración de tu API y la configuración de App.

Aquí tienes la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

Answer (score 0):

Gracias pero a lo que me refería es que para el mismo usuario, cada vez que repito la petición el token cambia.

¿ Puede ser que cambie el código que me devuelve porque cambia el tiempo de expiración y otras variables ?

Saludos.

Comment: La url de la api no debe devolver un token, el token lo tiene que pasar la url que realiza la petición para que la api verifique que la petición se encuentra protegida por un token.